# Binary Search Tree segfaults

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I have been struggling with this for a while. I have a BST that is designed to increment a counter whenever a duplicate is encountered when inserting. This works exactly as designed.

The tree discards this element and the tree remains unchanged. I want to however delete the original element that was in the tree so that third insertion of a duplicate element will not increase the counter. I get segfaults when I run the program. See below for the code. GDB says that the segfault takes place in the InsertInto() method and ValGrind complains about a bunch of memory leaks that I cannot find.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
struct BSTreeNode
{
    int mData;
    BSTreeNode *mLeft, *mRight;
    BSTreeNode(int i)
    {
        mData = i;
        mLeft = NULL;
        mRight = NULL;
    }
    ~BSTreeNode()
    {
        delete mLeft;
        delete mRight;
    }
};

class BSTree {
    private:
        BSTreeNode * mRoot;
        bool mWithDeletion;
    public:
        int mDupCounter;
        BSTree():mRoot(NULL),mDupCounter(0),mWithDeletion(false){}
        BSTree(bool _withDelete):mRoot(NULL),mDupCounter(0),mWithDeletion(_withDelete){}
        ~BSTree()
        {
            delete mRoot;
        }

        BSTreeNode * FindSmallest(BSTreeNode *& _node)
        {
            if (!_node->mLeft)
                return _node;
            else
                return FindSmallest(_node->mLeft);      
        }

        void DeleteNode(BSTreeNode *& _node)
        {
            if (!_node->mLeft && !_node->mRight) // no subtrees
            {
                delete _node;
                _node = NULL;
            }
            else if (_node->mLeft && !(_node->mRight)) // only left subtree
            {
                _node = _node->mLeft;
            }
            else if (_node->mRight && !(_node->mLeft)) // only right subtree
            {
                _node = _node->mRight;
            }
            else // both subtrees exist.
            {
                BSTreeNode * temp = FindSmallest(_node->mRight);
                _node->mData = temp->mData;                 
                DeleteNode(temp);
            }

        }

        void InsertInto(BSTreeNode *& _node, int _valueToInsert)
        {   
            if (!_node)
            {
                _node = new BSTreeNode(_valueToInsert);
            }
            else if (_valueToInsert < _node->mData)
            {
                InsertInto(_node->mLeft, _valueToInsert);           
            }
            else if (_valueToInsert > _node->mData)
            {
                InsertInto(_node->mRight, _valueToInsert);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "DUPLICATE FOUND!" << endl;
                mDupCounter++;              
                // delete the node already in the tree if we must
                if (mWithDeletion)
                    DeleteNode(_node);              
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        void InsertIntoRoot(int _valueToInsert)
        {
            InsertInto(mRoot, _valueToInsert);
        }
};
```

Comment: First, your middle two cases in `DeleteNode` doesn't actually `delete` the node you are deleting.

Comment: Properly deleting a node from a binary tree is a considerably more complex operation than your `DeleteNode` function makes it out to be. The only *trivial* case is deleting a leaf node. The remaining cases involve rehoming nodes (which *may* be trivial, depending on which side of the *parent* node the victim resides, and what the victim node's child-situation is).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to avoid counting the third duplicate by deleting the node?! Even if you'd got your deletion code right, you'd still count the 4th, 6th, etc. duplicate, though. 
You are ambiguously hiding the fact that a duplicate occurred in the absence of the node.

You are doing yourself a favor if you explicitly store a counter in each BSTreeNode. I'm sure the overhead is negligible compared to the repetitive non trivial deletion/insertion in the tree.

```
    else
    {
      cout << "DUPLICATE FOUND!" << endl;
        _node.DupCounter++;                         
    }
```

If it isn't for performance I would even dismiss the global mDupCounter and traverse the tree to analyze the results. And should the requirements change, you have a lot more options to calculate different numbers, e.g. a histogram of the frequencies or whatever.

Comment: This is for a research paper comparing various pair-matching algorithms with each other to see who is the fastest. And the paper is concerned with duplicates, not triplicates etc. If there are four instances of the number 2, then the duplicates counter should be equal  to 2 at the end. Also, unfortunately, performance is critical. The original code is peppered with instrumentation that I removed for this post. I actually compare a BST that deletes the original element with a BST that leaves it in. Hence the checking for a flag before deletion is initiated.